# How can I delete my profile (unix.stackexchange)?

Tags: support, user-accounts

How can I delete my profile on unix.stackexchange.com ? Thank you!
I have tried to find a delete function in my profile preferences but there doesn't seem to be anything like this.

Comment: Questions on the site itself should be posted on [meta]. Also: http://unix.stackexchange.com/help/deleting-account

Answer (score 3):

See [this FAQ entry](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/deleting-account). Since your account has activity, you need to [contact Stack Exchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/contact); choose the topic "I need to delete my user profile"